# Creating a MYSQL view that needs data from foreign keys

Tags: sql, view

I am new to creating MYSQL views and having some issues on how to join together tables to create a view of data from multiple tables.

Here are my table setups:

## twitter_followers

date, market (foreign key), handle, followers

## markets

id, name, region (foreign key)

## regions

id, name

This is the MYSQL view I want to create:

## twitter_analytics

date, handle, market (using market name), region (using region name), followers

I understand that I need to somehow use the market ID from the twitter_followers table to get the market name and then use the region id to get the region name from the market however I am very new to SQL syntax and having some trouble joining all this together.

I am sure this is pretty simple and looking at a working SQL statement will really help me going forward to understand how to do this and more complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT twitter_followers.date, twitter_followers.handle, markets.name AS Market, 
regions.name AS Region, twitter_followers.followers
FROM twitter_followers
INNER JOIN markets ON twitter_followers.market = markets.id
INNER JOIN regions ON markets.region = regions.id;
```